# Redirect some output to command prompt, and some to file?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to redirect **some** of the standard output to a text file, and **some other** to the command prompt.

I'm currently outputting all of it to a file, but I'd like to output some to the command prompt, so I can know at least (get some hits), on what's been recorded (since it takes like 10 minutes to run this code)

This is what I'm doing;

```
FILE *stream ;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "K_file.txt";

if((stream = freopen(ss.str().c_str(), "w", stdout)) == NULL)
    exit(-1);

std::cout<<"blah blah blah...";
```

Edit based on comment;

'some' is part of the code where I would like to explicitly specify, example;

```
for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"I would like this to go to the file - since it's detailed";
}    
std::cout<<"loop finished - I would like this to go to the command prompt";
```

This might not be the best example but I hope you get the point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what's the actual problem here.

Comment: Why don't you just open an `ofstream`, and use that for the stuff you want to go to a file?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks. How did I not think of that. I guess I will need to go through all my cout's and change them so they go to the `ofstream`, but that's not a big issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "abuse" standard output and standard error stream for that. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void main() {
    std::cout << "standard output";
    std::cerr << "standard error";
}
```

Now, if you [redirect](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) **just** the standard error to file...

```
your_program.exe 2> file.txt
```

...you'll get "standard output" in console window and "standard error" in `file.txt`.

*(NOTE: This is Windows redirection syntax - I'm sure you'll have no trouble doing redirection on other OSes if you need to.)*

Comment: I don't see how this is an advantage over simply opening an `ofstream`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You can mix-and-match between writing to file and to console without changing the program. Whether this is actually important is another matter ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class stream_redirector {
public:
    stream_redirector(std::ostream& dst, std::ostream& src)
        : src(src), sbuf(src.rdbuf())
    {
        src.rdbuf(dst.rdbuf());
    }
    ~stream_redirector() {
        src.rdbuf(sbuf);
    }
private:
    std::ostream& src;
    std::streambuf* const sbuf;
};

int main() {
    std::ofstream log("log.txt");
    std::cout << "Written to console." << std::endl;
    {
        // We redirect std::cout to log.
        stream_redirector redirect(log, std::cout);
        std::cout << "Written to log file" << std::endl;
        // When this scope ends, the destructor will undo the redirection.
    }
    std::cout << "Also written to console." << std::endl;
}
```